# ASPxGridView1.Selection is always = 0 and ASPxGridView1.GetSelectedFieldValues doesnt work

Tags: asp.net, gridview, devexpress, aspxgridview

simply I'm trying to get selected rows from devexpress gridview, but it never works for me, I have tried client side and custom call back, and tried server side, but it didnt work, spend 10 hours searching and tried every solution that I got but nothing worked for me, could someone please give me a hint, what I'm missing?, here is the code:

default.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div>

        <dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" ClientInstanceName="ASPxGridView1"  KeyFieldName="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowSelectCheckbox="True" VisibleIndex="0" 
                    Caption="Select" Name="Select">
                </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="ID" FieldName="pag_id_pk" Name="ID" 
                    VisibleIndex="1">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Name" FieldName="pag_name" Name="Name" 
                    VisibleIndex="2">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Title" FieldName="pag_title" Name="Title" 
                    VisibleIndex="3">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            </Columns>
        </dx:ASPxGridView>
        <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Text="Get Values" UseSubmitBehavior="False" onclick="ASPxButton1_Click" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

default.cs:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataTable table = null;
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack && !IsCallback)
        {
            string connectionString = ...
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rd;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Pages]", con);
            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(rd);

            ASPxGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            Session["dt"] = (DataTable)dt;
            ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
            rd.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<object> indexes = new List<object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ASPxGridView1.VisibleRowCount; i++)
        {
            if (ASPxGridView1.Selection.IsRowSelected(i))
            {
                indexes.Add(ASPxGridView1.GetRowValues(i, ASPxGridView1.KeyFieldName));
            }
        }

        foreach (var selectedKey in ASPxGridView1.GetSelectedFieldValues(ASPxGridView1.KeyFieldName))
        {
            if (!indexes.Contains(selectedKey))
                ASPxGridView1.Selection.UnselectRowByKey(selectedKey);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance...

Update:
when I used "asp:SqlDataSource" it works fine.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using SqlDataSource (instead of SqlDataReader)?

Comment: yes, this code above is just example of the problem I'm facing, in the real code I have to change the datasource and query dynamically depending on other factors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a databind during your postback/callback?  I think your grid doesn't know what rows it has in your button click event.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I modified page_int code by adding databind, but still it didnt work

Comment: @Yasser why are autopostback and usesubmitbehavior set to false?  Are you actually getting in to the button event and seeing that no rows are selected in ASPxGridView1.Selection?

Comment: yes, when button clicked I'm calling "ASPxButton1_Click" methoed, using debug mode I checked ASPxGridView1.Selection and always = 0.